# How would I reload data once the app is reopened?

Tags: swift, tableview, reload

I attempted to utilize `willEnterForeground`, but I don't think I grasp the concept. I'd like to just call `tableView.reloadData` once the app is reopened. What would be the best way to do this in swift?

I also have a `tableview.reloadData` in my `viewDidAppear` but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can register for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Don't forget to store a pointer to the observer and unregister it in `deinit`. You can also use addObserver with a selector.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I have added the weak.

Answer (score 0):

add the lines

```
 var vc: MyViewController = window?.rootViewController?
 if (vc != nil && vc.respondsToSelector("reloadTable") == true) {
      vc!.reloadTable()
 }
```

"reloadTable" must be a public method of MyViewController